# ITK Library dependencies error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, itk

I've been trying to use ITK with visual studio but i've been getting problems with the ITK itself. After sucessfully configuring and compiling ITK with Cmake and creating a new project accordingly, Visual studio can't find the paths of the libraries. I've tried specifying the paths on visual studio directories and even manually introducing them into the code but the problem is: There are hundreds of dependencies within ITK, it would take me weeks to link it all together manually, isn't there a way to make this process easier, or to avoid it at all?

Thank you in advance!

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jemXH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to reconfigure ITK, but this time disable `Module_ITKVtkGlue`. Then recompile ITK, and then try compiling your project again. I assume you [used CMake to generate](http://preshing.com/20170511/how-to-build-a-cmake-based-project/) your project. An [example](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/HelloInsight) can be found here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did as you told and the program compiled, however, i still can't run it as i get this error message stating that the ALL_BUILD file "couldn't be found". Any tips on that?